# node fs not found with snowpack using typescript

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, snowpack

I'm trying to create a snowpack project, which already fails by the basic start.

I set up a basic snowpack project, but when I try to start my dev server it will fail because of this line:

```js
import * as fs from "fs/promises";
```

Showing me:

```
▼ Console

[snowpack] ! building dependencies...
[snowpack] Package "fs/promises" not found. Have you installed it?
```

But I think node is installed...
How can I use `fs` with snowpack?

Basically I wanted to build an app with `selenium-webdriver` but this fails even more, since it imports more libraries that are not loaded. `fs` is one of them. And I don't understand what `rollup` is doing and if this will be the right way to 'bundle` (?) fs ?

UPDATE:

Using:

```js
import * as fs from "fs";
```

will work, when running `npx tsc file.ts && node file.js`, but it shows in snowpack I still get the error:

```
▼ Console

[snowpack] ! building dependencies...
[snowpack] Package "fs" not found. Have you installed it? 

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/user/snowpackproject/scraper
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c snowpack dev --polyfill-node
```